# Unknown Override specifier when accessing methods/object across classes

Tags: c++

What I want to do (c++ problem):
Enter main. Call Class A (and pass a value). Inside class A, I call Class B (and pass a value). Do some stuff in class B. Return value back to Class A. Do some more stuff in A. Return back to main function.
I get the error that obj3 is an unknown override specifier. I tried to create a simple program to showcase my problem;

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    B obj3;
public:
    int add3(int num)
    {
        int x = num + 1;
        int y = obj3.add2(x);
        return y;
    }
};
class B
{
public:
    int add2(int num2)
    {
        int y = num2 + 2;
        return y;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int g;
    A obj1;
    cout << "enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> g;
    int r = obj1.add3(g);
    cout << r;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which compiler are you using? Both gcc and clang complain about `B` before complaining about `obj3` (and neither mention "override specifier").

Comment: `A` contains an instance of `B`, not just a reference or a pointer, so it is necessary to *define* `B` before `A`, not just forward declare it.

Comment: Peter, you are right, class B has to be defined before class A if A depends on B. Thanks!